# How to add cucumber reports to cypress

Tags: javascript, cucumber, mocha.js, karma-jasmine, cypress

I am using cypress-cucumber-preprocessor to create some cucumber test with cypress. The problem is that I only know how to create reports in JSON or JUnit format. But I need them to be in cucumber format. Like it is done in java.

I found this link https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/79 but nobody come up with a solution.

Does someone have a custom reporter that creates cucumber like reports? Or knows when this functionality will be implemented?

Comment: I would like to try this. I will update if I get a chance to have a try on it.

Answer (score 0):

follow steps to configure report:

1. Import libs in `package.json`:

   - **marge** (Use to merge files generate by mocha)
   - **mocha** (Generate json for pattern mocha)
   - **mochawesome** (Generate json for pattern mocha)
   - **shelljs** (It will be used for the Node JS to be able to interact with the terminal)
2. Configure in `cypress.json`:

```
...
    "screenshotsFolder": "screenshots",
    "reporter": "mochawesome",
    "reporterOptions": {
       "overwrite": false,
       "html": false,
       "json": true
    }
...
```

3. Create file `index.js` in folder `report/` with [code](https://github.com/vcamposs/easy-front-end-component-test-with-cypress/blob/master/component-test/report/index.js).
4. Run tests and execute command `node report/index.js`.

Configure screenshot by the tutorial: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3654

The index.js code was based on someone other script from the Google (view references), this Github script is what I did for my friend.

References:

- Repo of my friend: https://github.com/vcamposs/easy-front-end-component-test-with-cypress
- Credits script merge files cypress: https://github.com/testdrivenio/cypress-mochawesome-s3/blob/master/scripts/combine.js

Sorry, i not speak english...

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I am looking to generate cucumber reports like. And none of these options generates them the way I want.